# How can I make my custom url helpers in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'd like this custom url helper to be accessible from controllers, views, tests... Ending with both _url and _path. Also it should have the possibility to add parameters at the end as a url helper.

```
def reviews(reviewable)
  "/reviews/#{reviewable.class}/#{reviewable.id}"
end
reviews_url Book.find(1) # /reviews/Book/1
reviews_path Film.find(3) # /reviews/Film/3
```

Review.reviewable is polymorphic.

*config/routes*

```
get "reviews/:reviewable_type/:reviewable_id" => "reviews#index"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would just define the routes as:

```
resources :books do
  resources :reviews, only: [:new, :create, :index]
end

resources :films do
  resources :reviews, only: [:new, :create, :index]
end
```

This will create the routes as:

```
books/:book_id/reviews
films/:film_id/reviews
```

This is the conventional RESTful way to define [nested resources](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources). And more importantly it works with the [Rails polymorphic route helpers](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.1/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/PolymorphicRoutes.html).

You can use routing concerns to DRY it if needed.

```
concern :reviewable do
  resources :reviews, only: [:new, :create, :index]
end

resources :books, concerns: :reviewable
resources :films, concerns: :reviewable
```

It gives you the named route helpers `book_reviews_path(@book)` and `film_reviews_path(@film)`. You can also use the polymorphic route helpers:

```
<%= link_to "Reviews for #{@reviewable.title}" [@reviewable, :reviews] %>
...
<%= form_for([@reviewable, @reviewable.review.new]) do %>
...
redirect_to [@reviewable, :reviews], notice: 'Review created'
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though my question has been answered a long time ago, I want to add another answer according to the title of the question.
So if you actually want to create custom url and path helpers, here's the answer with an example: [Generating a full resourceful path giving only the last resource to the routes helper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63808393/generating-a-full-resourceful-path-giving-only-the-last-resource-to-the-routes-h/63811113#63811113)

Rails docs:  https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/CustomUrls.html#method-i-direct