# Generating a full resourceful path giving only the last resource to the routes helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-6

**In short**

```
# routes.rb
resources :article do
  resources :comments do
    resources :replies
  end
end
```

I want `reply_path` to generate the same path as `article_comment_reply_path`

**More details**

I have some resources that I want to chain in the URL, but I don't want to give all these resources to the helper every time:

```
article_comment_reply_path(@reply.comment.article, @reply.comment, @reply)
# /articles/:acticle_id/comments/:comment_id/replies/:id
```

Instead I want to do:

```
reply_path(@reply)
url_for [@reply]
link_to 'View reply', @reply
```

But this will generate `/replies/:id`

I did solve this on a controller level, by checking if `:article_id` and `:comment_id` are set and if not, to redirect the user to `article_comment_reply_path`. But this causes 2 problems:

- Double redirect and a waste of server resources.
- The `href` in the `<a>`element is different than the page url, so more of a hassle to determine if it's an `active` link.

Is there a way I can get the url helper to generate a custom path according to it's parent resources?

Comment: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#limits-to-nesting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found  what you need here:
https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/CustomUrls.html#method-i-direct

```rb
direct :reply do |reply|
  [ reply.comment.article, reply.article, reply ]
end

direct :edit_reply do |reply|
  [ :edit, reply.comment.article, reply.article, reply ]
end
```

Comment: Good one! It works when using `reply_path`, but when using `edit_reply_path` it seems to ignore the direct and says it's an undefined method.

Comment: Simply add another direct helper.